# Winui3 MediaPlayer crashes when loading large video

Tags: c#, winui-3

The Winui3 MediaPlayer crashes, when I load a video into it. With small videos like 400MB, it's working fine, but my GoPro videos with 5GB or more lead to direct crashes.

The memory usage gets up and after 1.5GB of memory, it crashes with an Unhandled Win32 exception.

Here my code:

```
<MediaPlayerElement Source="E:\video.mp4" x:Name="mediaPlayer" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"/>
```

I think I need something like a cache mode or a deferred loading for the video, but currently, I am not aware of how this works.

Edit:

I updated my code a bit and now I get decoding error when I run this:

```
mediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(file);
mediaPlayer.MediaPlayer.MediaFailed += MediaPlayer_MediaFailed;
mediaPlayer.MediaPlayer.Play();

private void MediaPlayer_MediaFailed(Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer sender, Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayerFailedEventArgs args)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(args.Error);
}
```

Comment: I don't have any 5GB mp4 files so I can't reproduce this. I guess you should try setting the `Source` programmatically inside a `try-catch` block to see what is causing the app to crash.

Comment: Is it an x64 bit process?

Comment: Yeah, its x64. 
@AndrewKeepCoding I tried that and the exception is not handled. I edited my question with an error.

Comment: This site is english-spoken only and you should not put images of text but add raw text to the question instead [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Also it doesn't look like the real final error, please post a full Exception's detail. Altenatively, I don't reproduce with 5G files, have you checked you have the latest WinUI3 + WinAppSDK?

Comment: Well, I think I found out why it had crashed, but I don't know how to resolve this. Also, I now don't think its because of the video size.

Comment: Have you tried to create a MediaPlaybackItem from the MediaSource (so you can also easily set the starting point in case you have to resume the playback), and dispose of it before you set a new one? I.e., `var medium = mediaPlayer.Source as Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlaybackItem; medium?.Source?.Dispose(); mediaPlayer.Source = new MediaPlaybackItem(MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(file), [...])`. Handle the `BufferingEnded`  event of the `PlaybackSession` -- *I think I found out why it had crashed*: what did you find out? What is the exception?

Comment: @FrozenAssassine, now what's the error? I don't think `MediaPlayer` has such impacted issue. Have you solved this question? You can answer yourself for completion.